# Finding missing number from series

Tags: php

This code will accept user input from the command line.

The first user can enter the limit of series.

e.g: user may enter 5

After that, the user will be prompted for 5 numbers of a series.

e.g:

2
4
8
10
12

Here in this series, 6 is missing, so I am going to find the missing series from common difference series.

I got the correct output from this code. Is it the correct way?  Is there any other simple code to do the same?

```
<?php
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $count);
    $series = array();
    $common_diff = array();
    $prev_element = null;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $series[$i]);
        if($prev_element != null){
            $common_diff[] = $series[$i] - $prev_element;
        }
        $prev_element = $series[$i];
    }
    $c = array_count_values($common_diff);
    asort($c);
    end($c);
    $common_d = key($c);
    $prev_element = $series[0];
    $missed_no = 0;
    for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++){
        $diff = $series[$i] - $prev_element;
        if($diff != $common_d){
            $missed_no = $prev_element + $common_d;
        }
        $prev_element = $series[$i];
    }
    echo $missed_no;
    exit;
?>
```

example input

5
2
4
8
10
12

Comment: is it possible for more than 1 values to be missing? are series of 1 allowed? Are you considering negatives/invalid input?

Answer (score 3):

### Functions

The code can be more readable if it is broken into functions.  This also [separates the concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of reading in the series and calculating the missing element(s).

```
function readSeries($fileHandle)
{
    $series = array();
    fscanf($fileHandle, "%d\n", $count);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
    {
        fscanf($fileHandle, "%d\n", $series[$i]);
    }

    return $series;
}

function findMissing(Array $series)
{
    sort($series);
    $start = reset($series);
    $finish = end($series);
    $step = ($finish - $start) / count($series);    

    return array_diff(range($start, $finish, $step),
                      $series);
}

$series = readSeries(STDIN);
$missing = findMissing($series);
echo reset($missing);
```

The use of functions also help to make the code more reusable. The `readSeries` function can easily be used to read from standard input or another source.

The `findMissing` function takes advantage of some assumptions that can be made when a series is sorted:

- It would be impossible to notice whether the beginning or end elements were missed, so they must both be present.
- One the beginning and end values are known then every step along this range must be present.

It then uses the difference of the expected series calculated using the PHP [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I'd fill in the missing values like so:

```
//assume
$series = array(2,4,8,10,12);
$count = 5;
//get step-size:
$step = floor((max($series) - min($series))/$count);
//then check/complete series:
$complete = array($series[0]);//first element is valid
for($i=1, $j=count($series);$i<$j;++$i)
{
    while(end($complete) + $step < $series[$i]
    {//while the complete series + step, add missing value
        $complete[] = end($complete) + $step;
    }
    $complete  = $series[$i];
}
```

Now this is far from perfect, but it's a start